# python and DRF :__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'code' and 'username'

Tags: python, oop, django-rest-framework, python-class

I try to use a simple inheritence in DRF project. so I have got two classes. I try to access a class attrs in my second class. but every thing I get is `None` value for both.when I try to use initializer, I get an error, which is my title.

```
class AuthAPIView(APIView):
USERNAME = None
CODE = None
  
def post(self, request,*args ,**kwargs):
    data = request.data
    
    username = data.get('username', None)
    password = username

    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    user_obj = User.objects.get(username=username)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
                code = random_code_generator()
                
            
                Code.objects.create(phone_number=user_obj,code=code)
                now = datetime.now()
                current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                
                hour = current_time.split(":")[0]

                minute = current_time.split(":")[1]
                #send(str(username),code,int(hour),int(minute)+2) 
                self.USERNAME = username
                self.CODE = code
                
                print(self.CODE)
                print(self.USERNAME)
                print(type(user))
                
               
                
               
                return Response("we sent a code...")
```

---

```
class CodeAPIView(AuthAPIView):

def post(self,request,*args, **kwargs):
    code2 = request.data.get('code2')

    username = self.USERNAME
    code = self.CODE
    
    print(code2)
    print(code)
    print(username)
    if code2 == code:
        user = User.objects.get(username=self.username)
        login(request, user)
        token = Token.objects.get(user=user)
        
        Code.objects.filter(phone_number=user,code = code).delete()
        return Response(token.key)
        
        
    else:
                    
        return Response("invalid token")
```

my urls.py

```
path('auth/',AuthAPIView.as_view(),name='auth'),
#path('register/',UserRegister.as_view(),name='registraion'),
path('code/',CodeAPIView.as_view(),name='code'),
```

first, I try to use /auth route, which sends me a code, whan I print `self.CODE` in first class, it is changed and it isn't `None` value...
I expected to get values in my second class (CODE and Username). but when I print them, they return `None` value.

all at all.. the attrs in first class are changed from None to my value, but when I try to access them in my second class they are None(they arn't be changed)

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: I don't have any error or bug my friend, I just can't access first class attrs values in second class, It returns None value as the first value of attrs

Comment: please read the discription first

Comment: What’s with the title then…?

Comment: It’s unclear why you’d expect `self.USERNAME` from one class to contain values from a completely different class. But even if it did that, that’s the wrong way to pass data in a web server. Hopefully you’ll have *more than one visitor!* You can’t save information like this in a server side variable which is shared among all your visitors! What happens with two simultaneous visitors‽ Each request in itself needs to contain the necessary information, not server side variables.

Comment: thank you.. so what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `USERNAME` and `CODE` as class attributes in the base class and later you are populating these fields in the `post()` method of the same class. which means the values that you are looking for are stored in an object of the base class so the derived class has nothing to do with them. Do not forget that classes are supposed to be blueprints.

`USERNAME` and `CODE` are not the same for all the instances (Users) so they should not be defined as class attributes.
If you provide more information about what exactly you want to do, we may be able to give you a solution.

Hope this helped.